# Indexing long length of String for Solr

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have a string type data, which contains 26357 lengths.
while indexing above data using SolrJ it gives an error as below.
(In my personal test, it works well up to 14000 length of string)

**Error message :** Error from server at (my local host) Exception writing document id 5ba59584a96fef13 to the index; possible analysis error.

**Here is my question:**
 if I increase Java Heap memory for my solr will it be solved the above problem?
 OR is there any configuration for indexing long text?

Please refer my schema file as below and My Version of Solr is 5.2.1.

```
 <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" />


  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionincrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
   <tokenizer class= "...">
   <filter class="...">
   <filter class="solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory" maxTokenCount="300000"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
    ..
    ..
    ..
   <filter class="solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory" maxTokenCount="300000"/>
    </analyzer>
    <fieldType>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this filter for string of large length. mention your max length value of string

```
<filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="7"/>
```

If you are trying for token count filter 
Removing the filter `LimitTokenCountFilterFactory` from index and query analyser should fix the problem.